Can debezium reroute records from one table to multiple topics?
I have different kafka topics for different events on the same table. e.g. Do something when new records are inserted, and do something else when records are deleted
I tried using multiple ByLogicalTableRouter but ended up breaking debezium.

You can't do this in one config. You'd first stream the raw data into a single topic (per table/collection), then you'd use something like Kafka Streams or ksqlDB to query for the op and process those events accordingly.
